# Template String As Object Property Name

Tags: javascript, node.js, object-literal, template-strings, template-literals

Why does JavaScript not allow a template string as an object property key? For example, when I input:

```
foo = {`bar`: 'baz'}
```

into the NodeJS REPL, it throws a `SyntaxError` with "Unexpected template string" with a long stack trace. Property values are fine, however, which is not as unexpected. Similar errors happen in the browser, for example, Firebug throws a `SyntaxError` with "invalid property id".

Template strings are allowed in "computed property names". For instance, this compiles perfectly fine in all browsers that support the syntax:

```
var foo = {
    [`bar` + 1]: `baz`
};
```

and creates the object `{"bar1": "baz"}`.

**Why are template strings not allowed as literal object keys?** Is it for performance reasons? Template strings must be compiled, possibly at runtime (correct me if I'm wrong), which means every time it encounters this object, the interpreter will have to compute the object name. Factoring in things like "cooked" template strings, this seems like it could get slow, although we have had getters and setters since ES5. Firefox does not mention this as an error, which is why I found it unexpected. Will the syntax be allowed sometime in the future?

Comment: Isn't that  the reason, computed property names is introduced. Yes, you need braces around it but it also syntactically seems better as a generic solution addressing various scenarios.

Comment: I'm just rethinking my answer, and am not too sure it was correct. Now I am digging through the ES6 docs....

Comment: _Why are template strings not allowed as literal object keys?_ They are, you just have the syntax wrong...?

Comment: @bergi 's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194138/template-string-as-object-property-name?answertab=trending#tab-top:~:text=%40b4d4r%3A%20No%20%2D%20you,Bergi) or @nati Kamusher 's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67722507/8272035) should be the accepted answer. @bergi is succinct and correct 
97 upvotes
"...you need to use computed properties. Either var obj = {[\`${dyanmicKey}\`]: val} or just var obj = {[dyanmicKey]: val}. – 
Bergi
 May 31, 2016 at 14:14

Answer (score 90, accepted):

> Why are template strings not allowed as literal object keys?

Template strings are expressions, not literals<sup>1</sup>. You can only use string literals (and identifiers) for property names, for everything else - that is not known to be static - you need a computed property name.

> Is it for performance reasons?

No, that's unlikely. It's to ease parsing, and makes it easy to distinguish constant (statically known) property names from dynamically computed ones.

And mostly, it's a feature that no one needs. It doesn't simplify or shorten anything, and what you would achieve with it is already possible.

> Will the syntax be allowed sometime in the future?

Nope.

<sub>1: Even when they're called "template literals", technically they aren't [literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-primary-expression-literals). And: templates don't even need to be strings, they can evaluate to anything.</sub>

Comment: what about  
`

 var obj = {\`${dyanmicKey}\` : val }  

` 
?

Comment: @b4d4r: No - you need to use computed properties. Either ``var obj = {[`${dyanmicKey}`]: val}`` or just `var obj = {[dyanmicKey]: val}`.

Comment: Man, why not though. They just don't want people to put expressions in there huh...

Comment: @Bergi How would one fix the following: ``profile.preferences.networks[${network.name}]``

Comment: @KarlMorrison Just drop the `${` `}` parts?

Comment: @Bergi Ah damn, it took away the squint comments, look again here `\`profile.preferences.networks[${network.name}]`\`

Comment: @KarlMorrison And what's the problem that needs to be fixed with that?

Comment: Excellent @Bergi ! Everyone try this : const k = 'key'; const o = {[k]:1}; console.log(o);

Comment: On a related note, is # allowed inside key string?

Comment: @SafalPillai Not inside an unquoted identifier name, but `{"#key": "value"}` is totally fine.

Comment: What does this mean: *"templates don't even need to be strings, they can evaluate to anything"*

Comment: @adiga A tagged template literal evaluates to whatever value the tag function returns, e.g. a regex or an abstract syntax tree or really anything.

Answer (score 31):

Object keys are expected to be Strings:

```
let obj1 = { name: "Alex", age: "28"} // this is a 'normal' style
```

If the expression provided as a key is not a string, the engine will attempt to **Coerse** it into a string.

```
let obj2 = { 5: "Banana", 10: "Apple" } // e.g. number key is coersed into string
```

Template Strings need to be evaluated first. Therefore are not 'coersible'. Hense, the engine throws an error, because it tries to coerse them (example 1)

Arrays, on the other hand, are naturally coersible to string, therefore can be used as completely legal keys

Moreover, arrays that contain template strings may be used as perfectly legal keys when creating an object, because the engine first evaluates the template expression, then  coerses the array into a string (example 2)

see examples:

```
    /* example 1 */ {`foo`: "bar"}   // Error: template strs aren't coersible
```

To be able to use a template string as an object key, just wrap it as single element of an array:

```
    /* example 2 */ {[`foo`]: "bar"} /* OK: {foo: "bar"}, the internal `foo` 
                                           template is first resolved to a native 
                                           "foo" string, resulting in array ["foo"],
                                           which then coersed to the "foo" key.*/
    
    /* example 3 */ const obj = {foo: "bar"}
                        const obj1 = {[obj.foo]: "bar"} // OK: {bar: "bar"} !!
```

Comment: Fascinating. I never thought about why an array works as an object key name, but now it makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 10):

I'm posting this answer to lift [@Bergi's very upvoted comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194138/template-string-as-object-property-name#comment-62585029) to an answer. If you want to use a dynamic value from a variable as your object key in your object literal, just use a computed property:

```
const dynamicKey = someCondition ? 'someKeyName' : 'otherKeyName';
const obj = {[dynamicKey]: val};
```

You could also write that as:

```
const obj = {[`${dynamicKey}`]: val};
```