# Firestore insert object field

Tags: object, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to save a value inside a field in firestore, like this image.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I want shopId to be dynamic, then it will contain date and time fields with a boolean value.

My objective is to track a user's Checkin history on different shops. Hope you understand what i'm saying here.

now this is my current code:

```js
checkInShop() {
  let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  if (currentUser) {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const batch = db.batch();
    const docRef = db.collection("userCheckInHistory").doc(currentUser.uid);
    const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    batch.set(docRef, {
      `${this.state.shopId}`: {
        `${timestamp}`: true
      }
    });
    // Commit the batch
    batch.commit().then(function() {
      AlertIOS.alert(`ShopId: Sent!`);
    });
  }
};
```

Is this possible to firestore?

Comment: [you can't use string literals as object keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35902149/6721919)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```js
docRef.set({ [this.state.shopId]: { [timestamp]: true } });
```

you probably want to set merge to true in this case as well:

```js
docRef.set({ [this.state.shopId]: { [timestamp]: true } }, { merge: true });
```

if you have to use template literals:

```js
docRef.set(
  { [`${this.state.shopId}`]: { [`${timestamp}`]: true } },
  { merge: true }
);
```

Comment: now I have another problem, about using {merge: true} how can I implement it inside an object field?