# Vuejs class-bind and class interpolation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the view I need to generate the following classes:

```
<div class="comp comp--lock comp--red">Foo</div>
```

The `lock` and `red` are based on state, where the following values for color are possible:

- `comp--red`, `comp--yellow`, `comp--blue`, and many other possible colors

Until now I was using a computed method to concatenate the class name based on data:

```
getCompClassName(){
  return `comp ${this.isLock ? 'comp--lock' : ''} comp--${this.color}`
}
```

Looking at Vuejs documentation I see there is `v-bind:class` that should resolve this in a better way, the problem I have is how to solve the `color` interpolation, since I would need to declare all possible colors.

```
data: {
  classObject: {
    'comp--lock': this.isLock,
    'comp--red': this.color === 'red',
    'comp--blue': this.color === 'blue',
    'comp--yellow': this.color === 'yellow'
  }
}
```

Is there any way to solve this using `v-bind:class` that scales better without having to list all possibilities or should I use the computed method to interpolate the class name?

Comment: Computed property will be good plus you get the additional benefit of caching as computed properties are not re calculated on every re-render unless its dependencies change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you not just use a computed?

```
computed: {
  classObject() {
    return {
      'comp--lock': this.isLock,
      [`comp--${this.color}`]: true
    }
  }
}
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5sknyauz/5/

EDIT: you could actually do the same thing in data:

```
data() {
  return {
    classObject: {
      'comp--lock': this.isLock,
      [`comp--${this.color}`]: true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Won't work with data. Also syntax is incorrect in computed example. But the approach is correct.

Comment: I'm trying your solution but it doesn't look like valid javascript. More info can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35902149/220272)

Comment: I think I have something following your solution, here is the bin: http://jsbin.com/qajokim/3/edit?css,js,output . To make it work I've changed the `key` value like `[\`comp--${this.color}\`]`. Not sure how valid is this, but it works

Comment: @a--m yes apologies, forgot the square brackets. Updated the answer and added a JSFiddle link. I'm pretty sure it is perfectly valid (at least I do it all the time).