# How to populate the string template variables in an array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've created an array of object and in some of these objects I need to refer to the properties of that object inside of it like this:

```
let fields = [

{
    "ATTRIBUTE_NAME": "PERSON_NAME",
    "FIELD_NAME": "name"
    "ATTRIBUTE_ID": 1,
    "RULES": [
        {
            "MSG":`${this.ATTRIBUTE_NAME} is not valid`,
            "NAME": "VALID_VALUES",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "ATTRIBUTE_NAME": "PERSON_JOB",
    "FIELD_NAME": "job"
    "ATTRIBUTE_ID": 2,
    "RULES": [
        {
            "MSG":`${this.ATTRIBUTE_NAME} is not valid`,
            "NAME": "VALID_VALUES",
        }
    ]
}
```

]
But this keyword returning undefined! I want the "MSG" property to pick up the attribute name and populate it for me. Does anybody know how to capture it inside the template string?

Comment: You can't, because the fields array hasn't been defined yet and thus its sub-elements haven't either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33194138/3551786

Comment: You'd have to define the object first then iterate through it and set the properties accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for your `RULES` property.

A simple demonstration:

```js
var obj = {
  id: 1,

  get info() {
    return `The id is ${this.id}.`;
  }

}

console.log(obj.info);
```

Applied to your code:

```js
let fields = [{
  "ATTRIBUTE_NAME": "PERSON_NAME",
  "FIELD_NAME": "name",
  "ATTRIBUTE_ID": 1,

  get RULES() {
    return [{
      "MSG": `${this.ATTRIBUTE_NAME} is not valid`,
      "NAME": "VALID_VALUES",
    }]
  }

}];

console.log(fields[0].RULES[0].MSG);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a self-reference like that, because the `fields` array and its sub-elements have not yet been declared. What you can do, instead, is:

1. Declare the `fields` array and its sub-elements first.
2. Then, iterate over every element and add the object you want in the `RULES` array.

**Example:**

```js
/* Declare the array and its sub-elements. */
let fields = [{
    "ATTRIBUTE_NAME": "PERSON_NAME",
    "FIELD_NAME": "name",
    "ATTRIBUTE_ID": 1,
    "RULES": []
  },
  {
    "ATTRIBUTE_NAME": "PERSON_JOB",
    "FIELD_NAME": "job",
    "ATTRIBUTE_ID": 2,
    "RULES": []
  }
];

/* Iterate over every element. */
fields.forEach(element => {
  element.RULES.push({
    "MSG": element.ATTRIBUTE_NAME + " is not valid",
    "NAME": "VALID_VALUES"
  });
});

/* Log the result. */
console.log(fields);
```