# Why does object destructuring assignment throw an error when using template strings?

Tags: javascript, syntax, template-strings

In JavaScript, it is possible to assign variables through object deconstruction like so:

```
let a = {b: 2};
let {b} = a;
console.log(b); // 2
```

Sometimes the property that needs to be accessed isn't a valid variable name, in which case an alternative identifier can be passed:

```
let a = {'words with spaces': 2};
let {'words with spaces': words_without_spaces} = a;
console.log(words_without_spaces); // 2
```

This works for both single quote strings and double quote strings. However, an error is thrown when trying to do the exact same thing with a template string:

```
let a = {'words with spaces': 2};
let {`words with spaces`: words_without_spaces} = a;
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected template string
```

Why does using a template string here cause an error whereas other strings don't? I understand that the template string could be defined as a variable beforehand and then passed using computed property brackets, but I'm just curious as to what the reason is behind the above code not working.

Comment: Simply because property keys must be delimited by `'` or `"` - a string literal not a template expression.

Comment: I think this may answer at least partially: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194138/template-string-as-object-property-name/35902149#35902149

Comment: Thank you, that post answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language syntax allows for a property name in an object initializer or a descructuring left-hand-side of an assignment to be a string literal but not a template. That's just the way the grammar is defined.