# Unexpected template string when Creating Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I create a Object like below,

```
var s = {
  `1234`:`string`
}
```

But, It will throw the below Error,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected template string
```

How Can I create Such Elements?

Comment: Object declaration in javascript is done using single or double quotes and not backquotes `var s = {
  "1234": "string"
}`

Comment: replace `\`` with `'` single quote

Comment: Further answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33194138)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using quotes instead of backticks, try this:

```
 var s  = { '123': 'string'}
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) with brackets, because the [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) returns a string, which works like a variable.

```js
var object = { [`1234`]:`string` };

console.log(object);
```

Comment: With that we can also avoid the backquote in `1234`. Simply `[1234]`

Comment: i think it's more how to use a template litral as key (with computed values), not just taking a constant as key. but i might be wrong ...