# `use strict` is not working when we use template literals

Tags: javascript, template-literals, use-strict

If I enclose `use strict` with backticks/template literals, 'use strict' is not working as expected. Can you share the reason behind it? Are there any similar exceptional statements where template literals are not going to work as expected?

```js
`use strict`;
x = 3.14;  // Ideally it should  cause an error (as x is not defined).
alert(x);
```

```
`use strict`; // if we enclose in single quotes or double quotes
x = 3.14;    // Ideally it should  cause an error (as x is not defined).
alert(x);
```

Comment: `use string` just doesn't work with template literals

Comment: I prefer template literal, so tried, is it going to work or not over this special string...

Comment: Why would you want to use template literals when it is just a simple string? "To invoke strict mode for an entire script, put the exact statement `"use strict";` (or `'use strict';`) before any other statements." [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#strict_mode_for_scripts)

Comment: Just because template literals exist doesn’t mean you need to replace every string literal with one…

Comment: Would you expect `\`use ${something}\`;` to work for a variable `something`?

Comment: Same reason why [template literals don't work as object keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33194138/1048572): they're not string literals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the [Use Strict Directive](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#use-strict-directive) is explicitly defined in the specification as an *[ExpressionStatement](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-ExpressionStatement)* consisting entirely of a *[StringLiteral](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-StringLiteral)* production, and limits the exact code point sequences to be either `"use strict"` or `'use strict'`.

From the [ECMAScript 2020 Language Specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/):

> #### [14.1.1 Directive Prologues and the Use Strict Directive](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-directive-prologues-and-the-use-strict-directive)
>
> A *[Directive Prologue](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#directive-prologue)* is the longest sequence of *[ExpressionStatement](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-ExpressionStatement)s* occurring as the initial *[StatementListItem](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-StatementListItem)s* or *[ModuleItem](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-ModuleItem)s* of a *[FunctionBody](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-FunctionBody)*, a *[ScriptBody](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-ScriptBody)*, or a *[ModuleBody](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-ModuleBody)* and where each *[ExpressionStatement](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-ExpressionStatement)* in the sequence consists entirely of a *[StringLiteral](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-StringLiteral)* token followed by a semicolon. The semicolon may appear explicitly or may be inserted by automatic semicolon insertion. A [Directive Prologue](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#directive-prologue) may be an empty sequence.
>
> **A *[Use Strict Directive](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#use-strict-directive)* is an *[ExpressionStatement](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-ExpressionStatement)* in a [Directive Prologue](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#directive-prologue) whose *[StringLiteral](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-StringLiteral)* is either of the exact code point sequences `"use strict"` or `'use strict'`. A [Use Strict Directive](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#use-strict-directive) may not contain an *[EscapeSequence](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-EscapeSequence)* or *[LineContinuation](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-LineContinuation)*.**
>
> A [Directive Prologue](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#directive-prologue) may contain more than one [Use Strict Directive](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#use-strict-directive). However, an implementation may issue a warning if this occurs.

<sup>Emphasis added</sup>

On the other hand, a *[TemplateLiteral](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-TemplateLiteral)* is an entirely different production than a *[StringLiteral](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-StringLiteral)*, and therefore cannot be a valid directive.

Answer (score 6):

It is simply designed that way.

From the [ES6 specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-directive-prologues-and-the-use-strict-directive):

> #### 14.1.1 Directive Prologues and the Use Strict Directive
>
> A Directive Prologue is the longest sequence of *ExpressionStatement* productions occurring as the initial *StatementListItem* or *ModuleItem* productions of a *FunctionBody*, a *ScriptBody*, or a *ModuleBody* and where each *ExpressionStatement* in the sequence consists entirely of a *StringLiteral* token followed by a semicolon. The semicolon may appear explicitly or may be inserted by [automatic semicolon insertion](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion). A Directive Prologue may be an empty sequence.
>
> **A Use Strict Directive is an *ExpressionStatement* in a Directive Prologue whose *StringLiteral* is either the exact code unit sequences `"use strict"` or `'use strict'`.** A Use Strict Directive may not contain an *EscapeSequence* or *LineContinuation*.
>
> A Directive Prologue may contain more than one Use Strict Directive. However, an implementation may issue a warning if this occurs.

*<sup>Emphasis mine.</sup>*

It clearly states, that for the Use Strict Directive to work, it has to be written either with single or double quotes, but template literals are simply not allowed for this purpose.