# Loop through Array and assign variables name and id

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, variables

I want to loop through an array and give their name.
I tried to use template literals, but it doesn't work.

```
 const colors = ['yellow', 'green', 'brown', 'blue', 'pink','black']
    for (let color of colors){
        const `${color}Button` = document.querySelector(`#${color}`); 
    }
```

the results I want should be something like this

```
yellowButton = document.querySelector(#yellow); 

greenButton = document.querySelector(#green);

.

.

.

.

blackButton = document.querySelector(#black);
```

Could you guys please revise my code?

Comment: Related, see [Template String As Object Property Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194138/template-string-as-object-property-name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach variables onto the window object, making it accessible as a global variable. However this is a bad practice, since it pollutes namespace, causing unnecessary bugs and much headache in the future. A much better approach to this is to use native javascript objects, as this is the exact use case it was made for.

With your example:

```js
const colors = ['yellow', 'green', 'brown', 'blue', 'pink', 'black']

const buttons = colors.reduce((accum, color) => {
  accum[`${color}Button`] = document.querySelector(`#${color}`);
  return accum;
}, {});

console.log(buttons)

// to access certain element:
const elem = buttons.yellowButton
console.log(elem)
```

```html
<button id='yellow'></button>
<button id='green'></button>
<button id='brown'></button>
<button id='blue'></button>
<button id='pink'></button>
<button id='black'></button>
```

Comment: Such an approach also deserves much more the usage of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead of [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Looking at it now, I agree with you. I will change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the browser, you can attach variables to the [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) interface and reference them as if they were defined in the global scope.

```js
for (const color of colors) {
  window[`${color}Button`] = document.querySelector(`#${color}`)
}

console.log(redButton.textContent)
```

However, as others have mentioned, it may not be the best approach.