# How to write dynamic json object inside an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Desired output--

```json
[
  {
    "group1": {
      "Token1": "123443423",
      "Token2": "121414141"
    },
    "group2": {
      "Token1": "123443423",
      "Token2": "121414141"
    }
  }
]
```

Group1 and group2 is dynamic and also the token1 and token2 value is dynamic. So i write this way --

```
[ {`${group1}`:{ 
         "Token1" : `${token1}`,
         "Token2" : `${token2}`
              },
        `${group2}`:{ 
         "Token1" : `${token1}`,
         "Token2" : `${token2}`
              }
 }]
```

But `${group1}` shows error unexpected token ` (template literate).

Comment: your question is not clear show your code associated with this json also describe more about what you want to achieve

Comment: i wrote the desired output above . the dynamic data in group1,group2 can be anything  and those are variables coming from form input and i need to put that groups inside json array which further consists on many objects.

Comment: Wrap the template literals in `[ ]` when defining dynamic keys. (Or, you could set the properties separately rather than using an object literal.) But I don't see the point in a template literal at all, you can just write `[group1]` and `token1`, etc

Comment: @CherryDT your comment is the ans i was looking specifically . Thank you.

Comment: Check this link; 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194138/template-string-as-object-property-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. [Specific]**

```
// helper function
function createGroup(groupName, token1, token2) {
  const group = {};
  group[groupName] = {
    Token1: token1,
    Token2: token2
  };
  return group;
}

//and then create a result output
var result = [
  createGroup('group1', group1token1, group1token2),
  createGroup('group2', group2token1, group2token2),
]
```

**2. [More general]** For multiple paramenters (more than fixed 2):

your `parametersObject` have to be as:

```
{
  Token1: 'token_1_value_here',
  Token2: 'token_2_value_here',
  ...
  ParameterN: 'parameter_n_value_here',
  ...
}
```

And then:

```
// helper function 2
function createGroup(groupName, parametersObject) {
  const group = {};
  group[groupName] = parametersObject;
  return group;
}

//and then create a result output
var result = [
  createGroup('group1', group1parametersDto),
  createGroup('group2', group2parametersDto)
]
```

Comment: it works. However if i have to pass 40 variables then i should  to pass those 40 parameter into helper function?

Comment: Please, share the parameters object DTO example. I will update the answer

Comment: Updated. for more general case

Answer (score 0):

in your way you can create object with variables value this way . there was syntax error in your approach, template literals are not allowed for object key inside object directly

```js
var group = "group",
      Token1 = "123443423",
      Token2 = "121414141"
var newObject = 
{
  [group + "1"] : {Token1 , Token2},
  [group + "2"] : {Token1 , Token2},
  [group + "3"] : {Token1 , Token2},
  [group + "4"] : {Token1 , Token2}    
}
console.log(newObject)
```

there is also more easy way to do same which is more conveneint
example below

```js
var object = {},
    Token1 = "123443423",
    Token2 = "121414141"

object["group1"] = {Token1,Token2}
object["group2"] = {Token1,Token2}
object["group3"] = {Token1,Token2}

console.log(object)
```