# Use media query breakpoint inside global styles with Chakra UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm trying to use a media query breakpoint inside Chakra UI [global styles](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/features/global-styles).

This is what I tried but [you can't use template literals for property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194138/template-string-as-object-property-name):

```
import { ChakraProvider, extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const theme = extendTheme({
  styles: {
    global: (props) => ({
      `@media screen and (max-width: ${props.theme.breakpoints.sm})`: {
        div: {
          border: "1px solid",
        },
      },
    }),
  }
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <div>Hello world!</div>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I also tried concatenating the property name but it's no valid either:

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  styles: {
    global: (props) => ({
      "@media screen and (max-width: " + props.theme.breakpoints.sm + ")": {
        div: {
          border: "1px solid",
        },
      },
    }),
  }
});
```

The only way around it I found is hardcoding the value instead of reading it from `props.theme`:

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  styles: {
    global: {
      "@media screen and (max-width: 30em)": {
        div: {
          border: "1px solid",
        },
      },
    },
  }
});
```

Is there any other way around this? I couldn't find this scenario in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access dynamic property name using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation).

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  styles: {
    global: (props) => ({
       [`@media screen and (max-width: ${props.theme.breakpoints.sm})`] : {
        div: {
          border: "1px solid",
        },
      },
    }),
  }
});
```