# difference between alert() and alert``

Tags: javascript

I am testing my application for security purpose and while doing that I came across this scenario:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert`"Hello\nHow are you?"`;
}
</script>
```

Results in pop-up with message **Hello How are you?**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Hello\nHow are you?");
}
</script>
```

Results in pop-up with message **Hello How are you?**

Why these two scripts producing same result?

Use this link for testing:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert2

Comment: do be aware that even semi-old browsers will explode on the first syntax...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/what-is-the-usage-of-the-backtick-symbol-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a [**tagged template string**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#Tagged_template_strings).

Template strings are a different way to write a *String literal* which has been introduced in ES6 which gives extra features, such as the one you describe.

The reason you're getting back your *String* in the `alert` is because `alert` is `.toString`ing the *Object* which was passed into it, which actually looks more like

```
["\"Hello\nHow are you?\""]
```