# Use of apostrophe vs single quote/backtick

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax

I'm new to Angular, and while following along to a tutorial I made a slight change out of habit when writing the module states:

```
.state('sports.medals', {
    url: '/:sportName',
    templateUrl: 'sports/sports-medals.html',
    resolve: {
      sportService: function($http, $stateParams){
        return $http.get('/sports/${ $stateParams.sportName }');
      }
    },
```

This compiles perfectly fine within the rest of the project, no errors. However, when the call is made to this function, it reads the `get` contents as one whole string instead of parsing the contents as it should.

The correct way to call this is apparently:

```
 .state('sports.medals', {
        url: '/:sportName',
        templateUrl: 'sports/sports-medals.html',
        resolve: {
          sportService: function($http, $stateParams){
            return $http.get(`/sports/${ $stateParams.sportName }`);
          }
        },
```

using the     `` ` `` apostrophe/backtick instead of the single quote `'`

As a programmer I've almost always exclusively used the single quote when working with javascript and/or double-quotes within parameters, so this surprised me and wasn't immediately apparent. Is there a reason for this behavior that is documented somewhere? Should I get in the habit of using backticks over single quotes? I would like to avoid other such surprises.

Comment: Backticks are ES6/2015 for template literals - they're good to know but not required https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals - I would add though they can make code a lot more readable

Comment: Surely you've also almost always exclusively not use `${…}` patterns in your strings?

Comment: A very similar/related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27678052/465053).

Comment: Did you call the backtick an apostrophe?

Comment: "Did you call the backtick an apostrophe?" <- this right here. Apostrophe == Single quote. Backtick is it's own thing, I just did a 10 minute internet search trying to clarify and so many people get it wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The backticks are necessary for the string interpolation to work. This is an ES6 feature called template interpolation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals.

Sometimes it will be available to you, but it is still far from widespread in terms of browser support https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals. Get familiar with it and use it when you can!

Answer (score 6):

> Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick ` (grave accent) character instead of double or single quotes.

Template literals / string literals in javascript use the back tick. They are an E6 feature that is simply syntactic sugar for [concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat). Template literals are [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20literals) in modern browsers and are supported in nodejs. When not using templates you should either use double (`"`) or single (`'`) quotes.

MDN has documentation that will give more information on template literal use: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)