# SCRIPT1014: Invalid character in IE 11

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I run the command "npm run dev" then I get this error on IE11. Other browsers are still normal. "npm run start" runs normally. thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnWw1.png)

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this?

Comment: Please read once this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question details.

Answer (score 0):

That happens when some part features of your code is not supported by the browser. Your problem might be similar to this: [IE11 throwing "SCRIPT1014: invalid character" where all other browsers work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048455/ie11-throwing-script1014-invalid-character-where-all-other-browsers-work)