# querySelector method arguments are put into backtick, why?

Tags: javascript, methods, arguments

I've started Javascript 30. What bothers is like on given example code:

```
const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
```

Why are the arguments put into the backticks? I understand how to use double and single quotes and when I can use both. However I don't understand how and when to use backticks.

Comment: [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Where are you using backtick¿?

Comment: Oh, it's not displayed. I don't know why. However, it is put before audio and closed after closing square bracket ].
\`(audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]\`)

Comment: It's because SO uses backticks to `do this to text`, if you put it in a code block they would show up.

Comment: @James I used 4 space to display this as code but it didn't work. Do you know why? So I could fix that.

Comment: @Luke_Nuke I've already formatted the code in your question. But in general, you can select a code block (also multiple lines), and then click `{}` icon on editor tools, that'll convert the selected text to a code block.

Comment: @Teemu thank you for both, editing and advice! :)

Comment: this question is duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/what-is-the-usage-of-the-backtick-symbol-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backticks allow you to use the string [interpolation syntax `${}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation).

Comment: Right. You can only use `${}` inside backtick strings.

Comment: I can see the backtick now, it was irony, sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add expression in string with back-tick. This feature was add on ES6.

Answer (score 0):

Backticks are template literals.  They allow for evaluation of variables and expressions inside of a string:

```js
var a = 5, b = 10;

document.write(`${a} + ${b} = ${a + b}`);
```