# How to put variables inside double quotations in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to put variables inside res redirect inside the post route and then get that variable in get route. I don't know how to do it. Thank you.

```
router.post("/message", function(req, res) {
 var email = req.body.email;
 res.redirect("/passingemail/<%= email %>");  // I try to put the variable email like this but it doesn't work
});

//my goal is I want to get the value here 
router.get("/paddingemail/:email", function (req, res){
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/what-is-the-usage-of-the-backtick-symbol-in-javascript).

You can also just go `res.redirect("/passingemail/" + email);`

Answer (score 0):

```
res.redirect("/passingemail/"+email);
```

or with ES6

```
res.redirect(`/passingemail/${email}`);
```

Comment: Thank you it works. I don't know what was wrong with me. I have used this kind of method may time. I think my mind was off.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
router.post("/message", function(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    res.redirect("/passingemail/" + email);  
});
```