# How to write long MySQL queries in node JS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

How to write long MySQL queries on many lines instead of one very long line for easy reading and modifying.
I only know this way to write them:

```
app.get('/example', function(req, res){
  x = 'SELECT doctors_schedule.*, employees.employee_name, doctors.degree FROM doctors_schedule JOIN employees ON employees.employee_id = doctors_schedule.doctor_id JOIN doctors ON doctors.doctor_id = employees.employee_id ORDER BY employees.employee_id';
  connection.query(x, function(error, rows, fields){
    if(error){console.log(error);}
    res.json(rows);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (template strings):

```
app.get('/example', function(req, res){
  const x = `SELECT doctors_schedule.*, employees.employee_name, doctors.degree 
    FROM doctors_schedule
    JOIN employees ON employees.employee_id = doctors_schedule.doctor_id
    JOIN doctors ON doctors.doctor_id = employees.employee_id
    ORDER BY employees.employee_id`;

  connection.query(x, function(error, rows, fields){
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
    res.json(rows);
  });
});
```

This feature is available since Node.js v.4.0.0.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can not imagine that it is that simple

Answer (score 1):

es6 brought us template literals. You can use backticks, and span multiple lines easily. Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/what-is-the-usage-of-the-backtick-symbol-in-javascript):

```
app.get('/example', function(req, res){
  x = `
     SELECT doctors_schedule.*, employees.employee_name, doctors.degree
     FROM doctors_schedule
     JOIN employees ON employees.employee_id = doctors_schedule.doctor_id
     JOIN doctors ON doctors.doctor_id = employees.employee_id
     ORDER BY employees.employee_id
  `;
  connection.query(x, function(error, rows, fields){
    if(error){console.log(error);}
    res.json(rows);
  });
});
```