# Want to know how constructing URL works while creating Server and route. As well want to know about => command

Tags: javascript, json

```
const buildUrl = (version, path) => `api/${version}/${path}`;
```

what does this do? 
How does this work?
what is that =>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the usage of the backtick symbol (\`) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/what-is-the-usage-of-the-backtick-symbol-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The => is whats called an arrow function, read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

These two are the same with a few small differences, that doesn't come into effect here:

```
(version, path) => `api/${version}/${path}`

function(version, path) {
  return `api/${version}/${path}`
}
```

if the backticks (``) in the string are used to create template string,
so they can a string and place variables (version, path) into them as denoted by the `${}`.

```
`api/${version}/${path}`
```

If the version is `1.0.0` and path is `home`, then the string template will return
`api/1.0.0/home`

Read more about template strings here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

The lamda => causes your buildUrl constant to turn into a function that can be called like any other function where "version" and "path" become parameters of your function.

```
buildUrl("test1","test2")
```

… would simply return "api/test1/test2"

Surrounding your string with the back ticks "`" will cause the string to be interpolated which causes each variable contained in ${somevar} to be evaluated or rendered.