# Put full webpage in document.write();

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot link to another page with my code for a popup window, so I have to use document.write however it doesn't even open the popup when i click the button.
For example, this code works:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<script>alert('test')<\/script>");
myWindow.document.close();
var p = document.createElement("p")
p.innerHTML = "This is the source window!";
opener.document.querySelector("body").appendChild(p)
}
</script>
```

However, when I add elements such as a divider, it doesn't work. For example:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<div>
<div id="test">
<p>Test</p>
<br>
</div>
</div>");
myWindow.document.close();
var p = document.createElement("p")
p.innerHTML = "This is the source window!";
opener.document.querySelector("body").appendChild(p)
}
</script>
```

Comment: You know a valid HTML document has a DTD, html, head and body elements, and the head is for metacontent like linking a stylesheet, and body is the place where to show the actual content. All those elements have to be created before trying to use them.

Comment: Yeah, that's not my full code, just showing the part I need help with. If it helps, the actual popup window won't open. Adding those elements still won't work. It just won't open.

Comment: You can't have literal new lines like that in a double-quoted JavaScript string. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types. You can spot errors like this by checking the console. Also, you would need to escape the quotes within your string, anyway (for example, in `<div id="test">`).

Comment: Even if we take away the syntax errors in you code above, not sure it would still work.   Your opening a new window, populating it with html, and then instantly closing it.   Your first example will show the window, because you have used alert, and this will block script execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 issues:

## 1 You used double quotes in a wrong way

```
myWindow.document.write("<div>
<div id="test">
```

instead it should be

```
myWindow.document.write("<div>
<div id='test'>
```

## 2 In JavaScript you can not use line break using double quotes,

this is wrong

```
myWindow.document.write("<div>
<div id="test">
<p>Test</p>
```

it should be

```
myWindow.document.write("<div><div id="test"><p>Test</p>....
```

Finally

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<div><div id='test'><p>Test</p><br></div></div>");
myWindow.document.close();
var p = document.createElement("p")
p.innerHTML = "This is the source window!";
opener.document.querySelector("body").appendChild(p)
}
</script>
```

Refer to [What is the usage of the backtick symbol (`) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/what-is-the-usage-of-the-backtick-symbol-in-javascript) if you want to write html in JS