# How can jQuery append() with backquote (``) miss/won't render a string variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla3.0, yoothemes

I'm building several carousels on a webpage with jQuery by calling all the information I need from YouTube with the Youtube Data API v3. 
After doing the designing and the functions I'm struggling with one simple thing that I cannot understand.

I use ``` append(``) ``` so that I can append all the HTML that I need to the element that I want, and also inserting other informations with the variables in the `${var}` notation.

Everything works fine EXCEPT for a single string variable `preview`. It's like it not recognized as a variable and in the final output is rendered like a string chunck.
Now some code.

This is the preparation for calling the function that loads everything:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var apikey = 'my-api-key';
    var URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems';
    var playlists = {
        1: 'PL549CFEF61BF98279',
        2: 'PLX_IxBH-yGtonzSE2zyplhI2oky7FWvbE',
        3: 'PL038B3F56D598DD61',
        4: 'PLDDFDDD10E5584056',
        5: 'PLD4F65416EB11640F',
    }

    loadVids(apikey, URL, playlists);
});
```

Next **loadVids**, for every youtube playlist call `getJSON()` and retrieve the data:

```
function loadVids(apikey, URL, playlists) {
    for (const menuid in playlists) {
        var options = { part: 'snippet', key: apikey, maxResults: 20, playlistId: playlists[menuid] }
        jQuery.getJSON(URL, options, function (data) {
            resultsLoop(data, menuid, apikey);
        });
    }
}
```

then **resultLoop** using `each()` puts all the information inside some HTML to be appended somewhere in the webpage (i stripped all the original attributes to keep it readable).

```
function resultsLoop(data, menuid) {
    jQuery.each(data.items, function () {

        var alttext = this.snippet.title;
        var title = alttext.substring(0, 57) + '&hellip;'
        var vid = this.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
        var preview = this.snippet.thumbnails.standard.url;

        jQuery("#carousel-" + menuid + " ul")
        .append(`
<li>
    <article>
        <div>
            <a href="//www.youtube.com/watch?v=${vid}&fs=1&autoplay=0&rel=0">
                <img alt="${alttext}" src="${preview}">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4><a href="/index.php?Itemid=${menuid}" title="${alttext}">${title}</a></h4>
        </div>
    </article>
</li>
`);
    });
}
```

At the end of it the `<img>` tag is

```html
<img alt="some text" src="/$%7Bpreview%7D">
```

I tried to:

- change the name of the variable
- console logging it before, after `append()`, without issues
- `typeof` says it's a normal string
- it gives me the same result on every browser

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong, and only `preview` doesn't work, all the other variables in the `append()` are working properly.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate that behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/08zxonL1/. Could you create a snippet which shows this happening.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan omg, in the jsfiddle it works
https://jsfiddle.net/u4q9jfy8/
I'm _so_ frustrated, [this is the page that gives me the error](https://viavai.tv/2-uncategorised/740-home-2)

Comment: If you view the source of your page you can see the problem isn't in JS - your JS is being output with the encoded value, not the interpolated string, eg: `<img alt="${alttext}" src="/$$%7Bpreview%7D">` (Line 574)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm not an ace in javascript, what can I do to make the string to be interpolated? What can I begin with?
Including externally the code with a js file can help?

Comment: I inspected the your page and saw that your code is `src="/$$%7Bpreview%7D"` not  `src="${preview}"`

Comment: If you output a correct value it will work. The issue is simply that somehow you're outputting `/$$%7Bpreview%7D` in your source code. If you change that to `${preview}` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using concat as you have already did for  jQuery("#carousel-" + menuid + " ul")  !!

Example: (Please use this code for append and check, I have used single quote and not backquote as it is not accepted by js validation)

```
jQuery("#carousel-" + menuid + " ul").append('<li><article><div><a href="//www.youtube.com/watch?v=${vid}&fs=1&autoplay=0&rel=0"><img alt="'+alttext+'" src="'+preview+'"></a></div><div><h4><a href="/index.php?Itemid='+menuid+'" title="'+alttext+'">'+title+'</a></h4></div></article></li>');
```

and remove all white spaces from the append string. I hope it is what looking for.

Comment: Not accepted by js validation? Then what about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40062505/1483287

Answer (score -1):

Just to let you know, all the above was working on a Joomla page.

Taking all the code, apart from the `jQuery(document).ready(function(){...loadVids()...}`, and putting it on a .js file resolved everything.

I think there is some filter that won't let you inject external resources like https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lmuUD9_eDnY/sddefault.jpg in the page with javascript alone (and that's clever), but the filter doesn't apply if you include a .js file within the website itself.

A mediocre workaround for a mediocre javascript code. Thanks to Rory in the comments that gave me some insight.