# Javascript syntax what does foo`bar` mean? E.g. { userName: state`auth.user.info.name` }

Tags: javascript

I've come across this syntax a couple times in different contexts and wonder what it means.  My guess is shown below.

From https://cerebraljs.com/docs/introduction/the_architecture.html

```
connect({
  userName: state`auth.user.info.name`
})(function User(props) {
  props.userName // "some name" (value stored in 'app.user.name')
})
```

The syntax **state`auth.user.info.name`** is what I'm asking about.

Another piece of I code I found that uses it is shown below (changed slightly to show what I think the code does):

```
// import styled from './styles';
var styled = {};
styled.div = function(x) { console.log('x is', x);};

var Buttons = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 6rem;
    margin: 0.5rem;
  }
`;
```

When I copy the above into my code snippet into my browser console, I see that syntax **styled.div`long string`** simply calls the function `styled.div` with the string `bar` as such `foo('bar')` (backticks replaced with normal tick due to formatting issues)

*Sidebar: Trying to put backticks/backquotes into a question is amazingly difficult in StackOverflow because SO wants to style the string as code and removes the backticks...  but I digress.*

*So is my understanding of what the code does correct?*

**Is this simply a way to pass a string to a function without writing the open and close parenthesis?**  Or is there more to this syntax, like the [Javascript IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) syntax.

When searching on SO I found several questions about Javascript syntax, but did not find this one answered.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/twdkco5z/ there you are!

Comment: [Searching for "\[js\] backtick"](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+backtick) would also have found [*Usage of the backtick character (`) in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/usage-of-the-backtick-character-in-javascript), which also answers this question.