# How console.log statement works with $ sign in the quoted string value?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript.
I have the following code in JavaScript:

```
function Person(first_name, last_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;

    this.displayName = function() {
        console.log(`Name: ${this.first_name} ${this.last_name}`);
    };
}

let john = new Person('John', 'Reid');
john.displayName();
```

The output of this code is:
"Name: John Reid"

I want to understand how this works? What is the role $ is playing in this code? In this part of JavaScript language specification or some other library at work here?

Thanks

Comment: They're called template literals or template strings. Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: its a normal javascript feature that allows you to render javascript code directly into your string

Comment: If you're learning JavaScript from a book or some web resource, make sure it's up-to-date. Template literals are a relatively recent addition to the language. A learning resource more than 5 years old probably won't mention them.

Comment: You should starts with ` but ends with '

Comment: @daniel that is not correct

Comment: @daniel What? Noooo

Comment: Oh, maybe i mix up another programming language...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of the backtick character (\`) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/usage-of-the-backtick-character-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pure javascript. No javascript library used here.

The `new` keyword is used in javascript to create an object from any function. You have created the instance and then you are calling the `displayName` property which is itself a function and show the output as you have used `console.log()`.

```
 console.log(`Name: ${this.first_name} ${this.last_name}`);
```

is same as

```
 console.log("Name: " +  this.first_name  + " " + this.last_name);
```

In the first one, you are achieving the same output but using `template literals`.

> They were called "template strings" and introduced in ES2015 specification. [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

And the second one is the traditional concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

`${}` is used for string interpolation. The variables are added to a string using ${} and plain text is added normally. 
You also can use the + symbol to interpolate strings

`"Name: " + this.first_name + " " + this.last_name`

but it is cleaner if you use the first option.