# How to execute a function inside chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have this code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(
           tabs[0].id,
           {
              code:            // HERE I want much more space to write
              'var to_filter = document.querySelector("iframe").contentDocument.querySelector("body").querySelectorAll("tbody")[1].innerHTML; alert(to_filter);' 
           },  
            downloadFiles
          );
   });
});


function downloadFiles(resultsArray){
  
}
```

I have to execute a lot of code inside the `code` tag, and after that, I have to send a list of `links` to the `downloadFiles` function. The problem is that I cannot write all the code in the `code` field, I would like to use a function instead. How can I call a function to execute instead of writing only in that line?

------ Update

```
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(
           tabs[0].id,
           {
              code:'(${ inContent })()'  // ERROR
              //'var to_filter = document.querySelector("iframe").contentDocument.querySelector("body").querySelectorAll("tbody")[1].innerHTML; alert(to_filter);'
            },
            downloadFiles
          );
          function inContent() {
            alert("test")
          }

   });
});
```

I get: `VM138:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'` in the commented line above.

Comment: Use a standard function syntax and simply convert it to string, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532567).

Comment: Can you provide me an example on this post? I tried without success

Comment: The post I've linked contains an example. Show your attempt if you need further assistance.

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: Use the backquotes as shown in that example.

Comment: No way.. Thank you, could you explain me that?

Comment: The backquotes are special, see [Usage of the backtick character (\`) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27678299)