# Node/Express: $ symbol not recognising the input PORT 8080

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code, server

How can I get my PORT running on 8080? Do I need to install a dependency?

```js
const app = require('express')();
const PORT = 8080;

app.listen(
    PORT,
    () => console.log('its alive on http://localhost:${PORT}')
)
```

Terminal:
*API % node .
its alive on http://localhost: ${PORT}*

Comment: You must use backticks (`) in order to recognize ${PORT} as a variable within a string.

Comment: Use backticks ` instead of single inverted comma '

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52612901/13163131

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using template literals you need to write it as

```
const PORT = 8080;

app.listen(
    PORT,
    () => console.log(`its alive on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
)
```

[image: keyboard]

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52612901/13163131 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals for more info