# is there a way to use strings with some object's property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

it's hard to explain, bur lets go on with a example

```js
const exampleProperty = {
    log1: () => {
        console.log('log1')
    },
    log2: () => {
        console.log('log2')
    },
    log3: () => {
        console.log('log3')
    },
    log4: () => {
        console.log('log4')
    }
}
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // now here I want to run all the functions in the example Property
    // I imagined it something like
    exampleProperty.log${i}
    // but this is invalid syntax
}
```

There might be a real easy answer to this but as I am new i really can't imagine what to do

Comment: ``exampleProperty[`log${i}`]();``. Note that there is no `log0` property and you’re missing the `log4` property.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to enumerate *every* method

```js
const exampleProperty = {
    log1: () => {
        console.log('log1')
    },
    log2: () => {
        console.log('log2')
    },
    log3: () => {
        console.log('log3')
    },
    log4: () => {
        console.log('log4')
    }
}

Object.values(exampleProperty).forEach(p => p())
```

Comment: we also can use this 
Object.keys(exampleProperty).map(key=>  exampleProperty[`${key}`]())

Answer (score 0):

Working example, using [`backticks`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/usage-of-the-backtick-character-in-javascript)

```js
const exampleProperty = {
    log1: () => {
        console.log('log1')
    },
    log2: () => {
        console.log('log2')
    },
    log3: () => {
        console.log('log3')
    },
    log4: () => {
        console.log('log4')
    }
}
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    // now here I want to run all the functions in the example Property
    // I imagined it something like
    exampleProperty[`log${i}`]();
    // but this is invalid syntax
}
```