# Why does it say it is assigned a value but never used?

Tags: javascript

[image: Here is the image of my problem]

I tried changing the string, and tried repeating everything over and over. Nothing seems to work.

Edit: Thanks for the replies, it is working now.

Comment: Try to use *backticks* instead of `'` in `alert` function.

Comment: Typo?  The value `temperature` indeed isn't used.  Though it looks like you meant to use a template literal instead of a literal string, which would involve back-ticks instead of single-quotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of the backtick character (\`) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/usage-of-the-backtick-character-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks everyone, it's working now! ❤️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says that you create a new variable `let temperature` but you are not using it anywhere in your code
If you want to use it in the alert you should use backticks `` for s tring interpolation instead of single quotes ''

Comment: Thank you, it's working now ❤️