# I created a function in ReactJs but it's not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

Code:

```
 import './App.css';

function App() {
  const firstName = 'Toto';
  const lastName = 'Wolff';
  const age = 35;
  const job = 'Principal';

  const getFullName = (firstName,
    lastName) => '${firstName} ${lastName}'

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>Full Name: {getFullName(firstName,
        lastName)} </h3>
      <p>Age : {age}</p>
      <p>Job : {job}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Output:

```
Full Name: ${firstName} ${lastName}
Age : 35
Job : Principal
```

Comment: See [Usage of the backtick character (`) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27678052/1218980)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing syntax. [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) require backticks.

```
`${firstName} ${lastName}`
```

If you want to use single quotes

```
firstName + ' ' + lastName
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine its just you used single quotes '' instead of backquotes `` here

```
 const getFullName = (firstName,
    lastName) => `${firstName} ${lastName}`
```

full code

```
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const firstName = 'Toto';
  const lastName = 'Wolff';
  const age = 35;
  const job = 'Principal';

  const getFullName = (firstName,
    lastName) => `${firstName} ${lastName}`

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>Full Name: {getFullName(firstName,
        lastName)} </h3>
      <p>Age : {age}</p>
      <p>Job : {job}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes use backticks(Template literals) instead

```
const getFullName = (firstName,lastName) => `${firstName} ${lastName}`
```

[Learn about template literals here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score -1):

I would simply do it this way:

```
const getFullName = (firstName,lastName) => firstName + ' ' + lastName
```