# How to clear a variable after one run in a 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

With my code, I fetch a JSON document from my server and display the data on the frontend.
That is the JSON document: https://pastebin.com/56YEnY4Z

The code is generating an HTML list.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.array.length; i++) {

    if(data.array[i].orderStatus == 0)
    {
        statusName = 'Neu erstellt';
        statusColor = 'text-sky-500';
    } else if(data.array[i].orderStatus == 1) {
        statusName = 'In bearbeitung';
        statusColor = 'text-orange-500';
    }

    for(var k = 0; k < data.array[i].foodArray.length; k++) {
        li += `<li class="flex items-center justify-between"><span>` + data.array[i].foodArray[k].name + `</span><span>` + data.array[i].foodArray[k].price + ` EUR</span></li>`;
    }

    list = `<ul class="list-disc">` + li + `</ul>`;
```

The problem I got is that the first run is smooth, and after that, old data is getting in the second generated list. Is there a function I can use to empty the var *li* after one *for* loop run?

I declared the variables, and that code is *just a snippet* from the original.

Comment: [`empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Empty) statement is what you need.

Comment: declare `li` inside the for loop `let li = '';`

Comment: But why do you `+=` `li`. Try without that, idk, might work. I also think its because you dont have li declared, and youre just adding to it.

Comment: Slightly related: *[Usage of the backtick character (`) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/)*

Comment: cont' - *"... are supported by Firefox 34, Chrome 41, and Edge 12 and above, but not by Internet Explorer."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clear your li inside the second loop if k==0, meaning every time you finish the outer loop you reset the li as k will be equal to 0 after each iteration of the outer loop

```
for(var k = 0; k < data.array[i].foodArray.length; k++) {
   if(k == 0)
      li = '';
   
   li += `<li class="flex items-center justify-between"><span>`+ data.array[i].foodArray[k].name +`</span><span>`+ data.array[i].foodArray[k].price +` EUR</span></li>`;
}
```

Or simply add at the start of your outer loop

```
li = '';
```