# jQuery very long selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have jQuery selector which is very long, something like this:

```
jQuery('*:not(".navbutton, .navbutton span, #menuContainer, #rollmenu, #postersTheme, optgroup, optgroup option, .custom-select, .select-selected, #divSelectedSize, #divSelectedQty, #divSelectedCountry, #divSizeItems, #divQtyItems, #divCountryItems")').click(function(e) {
    // some code here...
});
```

Is there a way how to make this very long selector having each selector on a separate line so it would be better readable, something like this?

```
jQuery('*:not(".navbutton,
  .navbutton span,
  #menuContainer,
  #rollmenu,
  #postersTheme,
  optgroup,
  optgroup option,
  .custom-select,
  .select-selected,
  #divSelectedSize,
  #divSelectedQty,
  #divSelectedCountry,
  #divSizeItems,
  #divQtyItems,
  #divCountryItems")').click(function(e) {
    // some code here...
});
```

Of course, above hypothetical "shortening" does not work ending up in breaking jQuery completely, thus I am asking if anyone around here know if something like this can be done and if so, how?

Comment: you could try the backtick ` (note this is not a regular quotation mark rather this replaces them). This also allows you to use variables inside the text for example `\`I want ${fruit}\`` if the variable `fruit = "apple"` it would say "I want apple"

Comment: @Roe sorry, what??? English is not my native language, so I do not understand what you mean, maybe you could post it as a answer instead so I would understand? That is to take my pseudo-code and make it into your code example?

Comment: Aside from the problem, you should note that having a selector as long as that is a code-smell. It indicates that you should probably re-think your logic and/or DOM structure to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try the backtick `` ` `` (note this is not a regular quotation mark `'` or `"` rather this replaces them). This also allows you to use variables inside the text for example `I want ${fruit}` if the variable fruit = "apple" it would say "I want apple".

For example (pay close attention to the ticks):

```
jQuery(`*:not(".navbutton,
  .navbutton span,
  // all requirements
  #divCountryItems")`).click(function(e) {
    // some code here...
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution - it works, thank you!. Still, I did not even know about this "backtick" sign - what is it and how it actually differs from the  regular ' and "?

Comment: @fafa [Usage of the backtick character (`) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27678052) | [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Although this answers your question. There might be something fundamentally wrong with your code if you require that many classes and id's in your selector. It is hardly understandable in this form.